# LCD ribbon cable to hdmi/minidp

Tags: hdmi, lenovo-laptop, lcd

Long story short, burned out a resistor in my motherboard for the LCD display so that won't work.

Rather than possibly causing more damage by trying to change it I was wondering if there was a cable I could directly connect from the LCD to hdmi or if there's a website I could order something custom like that.

Photo port (DY612 eDP cable) to hdmi or minidp port on my laptop. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxRbJ.jpg)

Comment: Guessing not, may have to just replace the motherboard. If it exists it'd stick out on the side of the laptop pretty big & would be hard to conceal & close lid. If you somehow tuck it inside I imagine the soldering/modification would be just as difficult as that resistor replacement or harder

Comment: Just get a minidp to whatever monitor input you plan to use. In other words use an external monitor, but we don't know what you plan to use.

Comment: I wouldn't mind if it stuck out/no cover. It doesn't need to be pretty so long as it works. I plan to use the laptop LCD screen. Instead of the ribbon cable to the motherboard, it would be ribbon cable to the hdmi port on the side of the laptop. I just don't see anything online like that